# Drupal 6 acces denied on page in non drupal folder

Tags: php, drupal, .htaccess, drupal-6

I have a folder in '/sites/all/libraries/folder'.
In this folder some html files are automatically generated with a drupal module.
In my navigation block a created a link 'mysite.com/folder' that is a redirect from '/sites/all/libraries/folder'.
I can see the index.html. On this page are links to the other files that gets generated, like '2011-05-15_14:00_001.html'.
But when I open the file, I get an acces denied error.

When I go to mysite.com/sites/all/libraries/folder/2011-05-15_14:00_001.html', I don't get the acces denied error.
How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Drupal root there is a .htaccess file that will route all requests through Drupal bootstrap by default, you probably want to either:

- Place your generated files outside
  the Drupal installation
- Override the .htaccess routes so those are not
  checked through the bootstrap
- Set
  redirects to each individual file you
  have, in the same way you created
  your redirect 'mysite.com/folder' to
  '/sites/all/libraries/folder'.

Comment: thanks man, 'Override the .htaccess routes so those are not checked through the bootstrap ', this seems the best option, any hint on how to do this?

Comment: a nasty way would to be to put a rewrite rule on top of the default one in the .htaccess in the drupal root (near the end of the file).
but i don't know enough to advise you on this. you may check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html or some other tutorial on mod_rewrite.